# Regex that replaces newline with comma, double quoted strings replaced with comma

Tags: angularjs, regex, string, replace

I am working on a string validation. Essentially, I want new lines to be replaced with a comma, but I also want text that is inside of double quotes to maintain the space in between..

For example, if my input into a textarea is the following (in between the lines):

---

A "B C" D

E 123

F 456

---

I want it to output -> A,B C,D,E 123,F 456

In my AngularJS service, I can use `this.stringReplace(styleStr, '\n', ',');` to replace new lines, and then the Regex I have for my double quote validation is this: 
`styleStr.replace(/ +(?=([^"\\]*(\\.|"([^"\\]*\\.)*[^"\\]*"))*[^"]*$)|^(?!\n)*$/g, ',').replace(/"/g, ',');`

...where my stringReplace function is this:

```
   stringReplace: function (string, text, by) {
      // Replaces text with by in string
      var strLength = string.length,
        txtLength = text.length;
      if ((strLength === 0) || (txtLength === 0)) {
        return string;
      }
      var i = string.indexOf(text);
      if ((!i) && (text !== string.substring(0, txtLength))) {
        return string;
      }
      if (i === -1) {
        return string;
      }
      var newstr = string.substring(0, i) + by;
      if (i + txtLength < strLength) {
        newstr += this.stringReplace(string.substring(i + txtLength, strLength), text, by);
      }
      return newstr;
    }
```

Currently, the first line (A "B C" D) formats correctly, but the whitespace in between E 123 is removed, as well as the whitespace in between F 456. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe this: [`string.replace(/(?:\n+| *" *)/g, ',')`](https://regex101.com/r/oR9mR7/2)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes it works great for the specific example I gave, but if I just do A B C, for example, it is outputting A B C when I would be looking for A,B,C

Comment: Why `E 123` would not be `E,123` ? I didn't understand your rules :/

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I need commas to replace spaces unless they are on a new line or in between double quotes. In other words, new line and words between " " need to be treated the same way. Thank you so much for your help, by the way

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can do this replace [`(?: *"([^"]+)" *| +)`](https://regex101.com/r/oR9mR7/3) and then replace the doubled commas to only one... but I'm not sure about this

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I just hacked away at what you provided and ended up getting it to behave the way I wanted to. It isn't pretty, but it works. Thanks again for all of your help and getting me on the right track.